# Eclipse 4.4.0 - SRVE0190E: File not found: /console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

I have eclipse 4.4.0 & i am trying to run a simple  worklight application. But when i try to access application console via browser, i get the following error :

```
SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter:258'
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /console
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:258)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /console
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
at [internal classes]
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:205)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:209)
... 2 more
```

I tried looking it up but couldn't resolve this.
The URL i'm using is: `http://MyIpAddress:10080/MyProjectName/console`

**Environment:**

Mac OS-X 10.9.3
Eclipse 4.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention your Worklight Studio version, it'd help if you do that.

In case you are using Worklight 6.2, note that the Worklight Console URL has changed.
Use `http://your-hostname-or-ip-address:10080/worklightconsole/`